# Error when attempting to load a product

Tags: magento-1.9, error, theme, php-5.4, rwd-theme

I'm experiencing an issue with our site, as I am trying to rework the RWD theme to a custom design.

Just applying the unmodified theme results in the following error when you click on any product (the theme design applies fine, and site navigates properly until you click on a product).

```
Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media::isGalleryImageVisible(Array
(
    [0] => Varien_Object Object
        (
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [value_id] => 19905
                    [file] => /3/0/308-8_4cl.jpg
                    [label] => 
                    [position] => 0
                    [disabled] => 0
                    [label_default] => 
                    [position_default] => 0
                    [disabled_default] => 0
                    [url] => <website>/media/catalog/product/3/0/308-8_4cl.jpg
                    [id] => 19905
                    [path] => <server root>/media/catalog/product/3/0/308-8_4cl.jpg
                )

            [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
            [_origData:protected] => 
            [_idFieldName:protected] => 
            [_isDeleted:protected] => 
            [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
)

#0 <server root>/app/design/frontend/tlc_alpha/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml(48): Varien_Object->__call('isGalleryImageV...', Array)
#1 <server root>/app/design/frontend/tlc_alpha/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml(48): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media->isGalleryImageVisible(Object(Varien_Object))
#2 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(260): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#3 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(291): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->fetchView('frontend/tlc_al...')
#4 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(305): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->renderView()
#5 <server root>/app/code/local/Extendware/EWPageCache/Block/Override/Mage/Core/Template.php(14): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->_toHtml()
#6 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Extendware_EWPageCache_Block_Override_Mage_Core_Template->_toHtml()
#7 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('media', true)
#9 <server root>/app/design/frontend/tlc_alpha/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(53): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('media')
#10 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(260): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#11 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(291): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->fetchView('frontend/tlc_al...')
#12 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(305): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->renderView()
#13 <server root>/app/code/local/Extendware/EWPageCache/Block/Override/Mage/Core/Template.php(14): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->_toHtml()
#14 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Extendware_EWPageCache_Block_Override_Mage_Core_Template->_toHtml()
#15 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#17 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#19 <server root>/app/design/frontend/tlc_alpha/default/template/page/1column.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#20 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(260): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#21 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(291): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->fetchView('frontend/tlc_al...')
#22 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(305): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->renderView()
#23 <server root>/app/code/local/Extendware/EWPageCache/Block/Override/Mage/Core/Template.php(14): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->_toHtml()
#24 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Extendware_EWPageCache_Block_Override_Mage_Core_Template->_toHtml()
#25 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#26 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#27 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(91): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#28 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->defaultNoRouteAction()
#29 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/69/b9/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('defaultNoRoute')
#30 <server root>/app/code/community/ArtsOnIT/OfflineMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(46): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_StandardOverriddenClass->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#31 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/52/17/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(191): ArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#32 <server root>/app/code/local/Extendware/EWPageCache/Controller/Override/Mage/Core/Varien/Front.php(17) : eval()'d code(17): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_FrontOverriddenClass->dispatch()
#33 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Extendware_EWPageCache_Controller_Override_Mage_Core_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#34 <server root>/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#35 <server root>/testsite/index.php(92): Mage::run('test', 'website')
#36 {main}
```

Can anyone give me any greatly appreciated pointers on what may be causing this? Other themes work fine.

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem. This method is called for a configurable product.
I am also on version 1.9.0.1, which I see that you have said does not include the function. Is there a way to include it or any other method that exists for the same functionality?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140372)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140372)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of Magento is your site running? I'm asking because Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media::isGalleryImageVisible is a method in 1.9.1 and later.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am currently running version Magento version 1.9.0.1. the theme works fine on vanilla 1.9.0.1 install, and the built in rwd theme has the exact same issue on my production environment. Trying to compare files, but it's a bit 'needle in a haystack' with my level of magento knowledge. Any pointers would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: I checked the codebase for 1.9.0.1 and it's not in there. Looks like it's available in 1.9.1.

Comment: You're absolutely right - I misread your initial comment as being 1.9.0.1. Thank you, problem solved.

Comment: You figured it out really good. +1 for that